# Server Error in '/' Application. System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I am getting this error on some pages when deployed on server.

**My application is hosted on dedicated server & not on shared server**

[Live Page Link](http://newsite.glazierscenter.com/cart.aspx)

I am not sure how to fix this error.
I have read some of the posts on StackOverflow & asp.net forums websites.

In my cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Security;
using com.paypal.sdk.services;
using com.paypal.sdk.profiles;
using com.paypal.sdk.util;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;
```

Stack Trace

```
[SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.]
   GlaziersCenter.cart.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +8431
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +253
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +78
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
   ASP.cart_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in App_Web_sa5qpq1w.5.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +100
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Comment: You most likely need to contact your hosting service to change the trust level.

Comment: Which PayPal SDK is this - `com.paypal.sdk.services` ?

Comment: paypal_base.dll - http://code.google.com/p/dotnet1-netmovie-t7/source/browse/Code/NETMovie/NETMovie.Prototype.PayPal/bin/paypal_base.dll?name=paypal